# import tensor with mat format to tensorflow

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I am new in tensorflow and Python. I have an image data set in Matlab in a tensor with size : 96*96*5000 (image size , number of images) and I need to import it to Tensorflow. I looked at the Tensorflow tutorial, which says I should use TFRecords or CSV formats but I think this means that I save each image separately in csv format.  Is there any way to directly import my tensor to tensorflow?

Comment: If you can convert your matlab data to a numpy array of shape [5000, 96, 96], you can then feed it in TensorFlow through a `tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5000, 96, 96])`

Answer (score 8):

As Olivier said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620330/import-tensor-with-mat-format-to-tensorflow#comment62727615_37620330), the easiest solution is to convert the data into a Numpy array, and use TensorFlow's [feeding mechanism](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#feeding) to pass the data into your TensorFlow model.

The [`scipy.io.loadmat()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html) function in SciPy can be used to load a Matlab `.mat` file into Python, as a dictionary mapping Matlab matrix names (as strings) to Numpy arrays.