# Import matlab cell array into python for scikit-learn

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, data-import

I have a 1x81 cell array in matlab.

Each cell is a 30x30 matrix of doubles.

I want to store this in python (for use in scikit-learn) with the shape (81,30,30).

I've read a few questions here and worked through their code but I'm not having any success.

Comment: you need to reshape your cell array to a matrix then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620330/import-tensor-with-mat-format-to-tensorflow

Comment: I would suggest that you look at this other question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761419/numpy-equivalent-of-matlabs-cell-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this just using [`scipy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html). But you have to be careful because of some of the differences in the formats.

```
from scipy import io
import numpy as np

C = io.loadmat('test.mat')
print type(C)
print C.keys()
```

Outputs:

```
<type 'dict'>
['C', '__version__', '__header__', '__globals__']
```

So you can see that `scipy` is inlcuding a bunch more information  that we don't really need, but we can see your cell C.

```
C = C['C']
print type(C)
```

Ouputs:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Okay so that's got use the Cell from Matlab.

```
print C.shape
```

Ouputs:

```
(1, 81)
```

Which isn't quite right, but with a bit of processing we can get it the way you want.

```
C = np.squeeze(C)
X = np.empty((C.shape[0], C[0].shape[0], C[0].shape[1]))
for i in xrange(X.shape[0]):
    X[i] = C[i]
print X.shape
```

Outputs:

```
(81, 30, 30)
```

Voila, we have your cell in a `numpy` array. Just as a forward warning, in general `scikit-learn` takes a 2D array as an input, not a 3D array.

Comment: Thank you - that works perfectly! Thanks for explaining it through each step